# How can the energy of a spinning black hole be converted into magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, astrophysics

I've read about the Blandford-Znajek process, and what I understood is that the black hole is treated as if it were a conducting sphere spinning rapidly with an accretion disk around it, and the rotational energy of the black hole would be extracted and converted into a strong magnetic field around the black hole. What is the equation that shows this energy conversion? and what does the magnetic field look like?

Also can this process be mimicked in a lab if we spin a metal sphere with some material around it? or is the process more complicated than that?

Comment: If you have access to a library here is the original paper http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1977MNRAS.179..433B  . the mechanism is illustrated here http://www.helli.ir/portal/sites/default/files/kip_thorne_christopher_nolan-the_science_of_interstellar-norton_w._w._company_inc._2014.pdf  page 105